# findPreference undefined in SettingsActivity

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to mod the cyanogenmod settings apk by adding the battery percentage in the main menu however I am unable to do so due to this error: "The method findPreference(string)" is undefined"

I've heard that you can only call this from a preferencefragment (which explains why my code does work in let's say the deviceinfo tab)

This is how I'm calling it:

```
private void setStringSummary(String preference, String value) {
    try {
        findPreference(preference).setSummary(value);
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
       findPreference(preference).setSummary(
            getResources().getString(R.string.device_info_default));
    }
}
```

I already tried "SettingsActivity.this.findPreference(string)" as well as "mContext.findPreference(string)" but they gave the same error as well

Is there any solution for this, or maybe a replacement for findPreference?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `getBaseContext().findPreference(...)` ?

Answer (score 0):

You are definitely calling it in a wrong place. The code you have written should be a part of the fragment which extends `PreferenceFragment`

```
public class PrefsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
...
}
```

Also, if your SDK < 11 use `PreferenceActivity` instead.